# Javascript roaming settings using Win8

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I'm trying to use roaming settings in a WinJS app.  The code I'm using is here:

```
var test = document.getElementById("testButton");
test.addEventListener("click", function () {
     var appData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
     var roamingSettings = appData.roamingSettings;

     roamingSettings["test"] = "test";

     var lbl = document.getElementById("testLabel");
     lbl.innerHTML = roamingSettings["test"];
});
```

I didn't seem to have any issues doing this in C#, but in WinJS I'm just getting Undefined from the read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `values` property of the `roamingSettings` object, which is an instance of [ApplicationDataContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer.aspx).

Comment: I just rechecked the documentation and you're absolutely right - not sure how I missed that !

Answer (score 0):

Several examples give the following results:

```
var roamingSettings;
roamingSettings["test"] = "test";
var lbl = document.getElementById("testLabel");
lbl.innerHTML = roamingSettings["test"];
```

undefined

```
var roamingSettings["test"] = "test";
var lbl = document.getElementById("testLabel");
lbl.innerHTML = roamingSettings["test"];
```

undefined

```
var roamingSettings = [];
roamingSettings["test"] = "test";
var lbl = document.getElementById("testLabel");
lbl.innerHTML = roamingSettings["test"];
```

This one worked. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JARPm/2/). Look into what `appData.roamingSettings` is initially and let me know if this doesn't lead you to a fix.